# How do I gather the Inspect Element code as a string using c#?

Tags: c#

I've been searching around online but am too bad of a learner to understand. I want to programmatically get a .png link that I can find when going into Inspect Element on a page.
I've tried `WebClient wb = new WebClient();` `wb.DownloadString(url);` but it does not contain the source for a .png link.

Comment: `but it does not contain the source for a .png link` So you want to crawl link(s) to PNG image(s) based on downloaded HTML code from URL?

Comment: like the href or src or whatever its called where it shows a link and if u go to that link its the png. What I've tried has given me something that looks the same but when I put into a notepad and ctrl+f search for '.png' it says no results